# can this.props be used to style the div tag?

Tags: reactjs, reactjs.net

I would want to use the this.props data in the div tag. i have the color in the data which i would want to set dynamically . Would it be possible to use this.props in the div tag?

```
var cont =  {
      height: "90px",
  width: "20%",
  background: "LightBlue",
  display: "inline-block",
  padding: "5px",
      margin: "5px"
};

var Comment = React.createClass({    
    render: function () {
      return (
          <div style={cont}>
              <span>
                  {this.props.author}
                  {this.props.col}
              </span> 
          </div>   
      );
    }
});
```

Comment: `<div style={{color: this.props.color}}></div>`

Comment: i have a style added to it  <div style={cont}> , how do i add style={{backgroundColor: this.props.col}} again to same div?

Comment: Like this: `style={Object.assign({}, cont, {backgroundColor: 'red', border:'10px'})}` or use `style={{...cont, backgroundColor: 'red'}}`

Comment: @MayankShukla thank you ,above solution worked

Answer (score 1):

Look:

```
var Comment = React.createClass({
    render: function() {
        return (
            <div style={{backgroundColor: this.props.col}}>
                <span>
                    {this.props.author}
                    {this.props.col}
                </span>
            </div>
        );
    }
});
```

`this.props.color` here is a prop of `Comment` component and not of the div. You can use this prop wherever you want in this component.

As @MayankShukla said, for updating field in style object you can use `Object.assign`.

Comment: var cont =  {
      height: "90px",
  width: "20%",
  background: "LightBlue",
  display: "inline-block",
  padding: "5px",
      margin: "5px"
  };

  var Comment = React.createClass({

    render: function () {
           return (
    
          <div style={{backgroundColor: this.props.col}}>
           
 <span >
     {this.props.author}
     {this.props.col}
 </span> 
              </div>  
           
     
      );
    }
});  i have already a style added to it , how do i add background color with this.prop along with it?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<div style={{backgroundColor: this.props.col}}>
```

[Offical React style documentation](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/dom-elements.html#style)

Comment: i have a style added to it  <div style={cont}> , how do i add style={{backgroundColor: this.props.col}} again to same div?